# How to target specific wp_nav_menu in function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a specific class on my wp_nav_menu via function.php but I am not able to target a specific menu: This is what I got

```
function add_menuclass_active($ulclass) {
   return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group"', $ulclass, 1);
}
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass_active');
```

I tried also using with no luck

```
function add_menuclass_active($ulclass) {
  if( $ulclass['theme_location'] == 'CUSTOM MENU' )
   return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group"', $ulclass, 1);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass_active');
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner see answer below please

Comment: Can you do it like that `function special_nav_class($item){
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if ( has_term($menu_locations['primary-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ){\Place your code here\}` ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner that code looks like a code I got from the same question I asked but it gives the error as per my paste bin in this link http://tinyurl.com/pf2dvpb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to an [answer from wordpress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163555/how-to-target-specific-wp-nav-menu-in-function/163557#163557) I got this solution:

add this to your functions.php

```
register_nav_menus(array(
'top-menu' => __('Menu1', 'twentyfourteen'),
'side-menu' => __('Menu2', 'twentyfourteen'),
'footer-menu' => __('Menu3', 'twentyfourteen')
)
);

function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

at last you must select the option "Menu1" for the specific menu on which you have to add the anchor custom classes from dashboard Apperance->menus. [select menu2 or menu3 for other menus whose anchor links does not need the custom-class]

To add "active class" to the first menu item of the particular menu then try this one:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();


    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
if ($item->menu_order == 1){
 $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group active" ', $item_output, 1);
}
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

if the active class must be added to the first menu item of all menus then use this:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();


    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
    }
 if ($item->menu_order == 1){
 $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="active" ', $item_output, 1);
}
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theme location is stored in the nav menu arguments, you need to add it in your function parameters:

```
function add_menuclass_active( $nav_menu, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'CUSTOM MENU' )
        return preg_replace( '/<a /', '<a class="list-group"', $nav_menu, 1 );
    return $nav_menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass_active', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This doesn't output the menu with the class "list-group" at all while mine above did.